# Flutter masking image with svg

Tags: flutter, dart

So far I found in [the documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode-class.html) info about BlendMode in Flutter, but I haven't found the code example or something that will refer to exact usage of this enum in order to achieve masking in Flutter with image and svg file.

I found the [flutter_svg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg) library, but I haven't seen in the documentation that this feature is available. Also, I found a lot of examples for web(html/css), one of them is [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/masking-in-the-browser-with-css-and-svg/).

So, is it possible and if yes how to achieve masking like [this](https://dab1nmslvvntp.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/1462516168alpha-luminance-css-masked-img.png) in Flutter?

Thanks

Comment: do you have `CustomPainter` for drawing? i mean do you want do draw that cat using low level `Canvas` stuff?

Comment: @pskink, no, I do not have, to be honest I don't know where to start with this issue. I just have profile picture and svg, and I have to shape profile pic with that shape.
Can you advice? thanks

Comment: so first dtart from https://blog.usejournal.com/how-to-draw-custom-shapes-in-flutter-aa197bda94bf

Comment: This would be a good start for you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50698335/clipping-images-using-png-in-flutter)

Comment: so you already know how to make that "cat-on-the-water"?

Comment: @pskink I just fond it, I guess it will work. Thanks for help :)

Comment: well, i did not help you much, but...